# If $\{x_{2m}\}$ and $\{x_{2m-1}\}$ converge to the same limit, does $\{x_m\}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given a sequence $x_1<x_2<x_3<x_4<\ldots,$ I found both subsequences $\{x_{2m}\}$ and $\{x_{2m-1}\}$ converge to $\lambda^*$. In this case, can I say $\{x_m\}$ also converge to $\lambda^*$? (i.e. a sequence $\{x_m\}$ is divided into two subsequences $\{x_{2m}\}$ and $\{x_{2m-1}\}$)

If so, if the rate of convergence is superlinear for both subsequences $\{x_{2m}\}$ and $\{x_{2m-1}\}$, can I also say that $\{ x_m\}$ converge superlinearly?

What is more curious to me is the case where two subsequnces converge at different rates of convergence. For example, if $\{x_{2m}\}$ converges linearly to $\lambda^*$ and $\{x_{2m-1}\}$ converges superlinearly to $\lambda^*$, what is the rate of convergence of $\{x_m\}$?

Comment: If you try to apply the definitions of this convergence types, then you will realize that you can, for instance choose $N=\max\{N_{2m},N_{2m+1}\}$ for a convergence $\delta$ from $\lambda^*$. Same train of thought goes for the others

Comment: @Kevin But if they did NOT both converge to the same thing (i.e. if lambdas were different) then we cannot say that $x_m$ converges, right?

Comment: @guimption, you could use a similar argument to the selected answer to prove that it doesn't converge if the lambdas are different. Since each series gets arbitrarily close to the corresponding lambda, then after some N they cannot be arbitrarily close to each other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can conclude that the sequence converges. This is because, given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N_1(\epsilon)$ such that for all $2m>N_1(\epsilon)$, $\vert x_{2m} - \lambda^* \vert < \epsilon$. Similarly, given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N_2(\epsilon)$ such that for all $2m>N_2(\epsilon)$, $\vert x_{2m+1} - \lambda^* \vert < \epsilon$. Hence, choosing $N(\epsilon) = \max \{N_1(\epsilon), N_2(\epsilon)\}$, we can conclude that for all $m > N(\epsilon)$, we have $\vert x_m - \lambda^* \vert < \epsilon$.

Comment: @DominicMichaelis Yes, you are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If both subsequences converge to the same limit we surely see that the sequence has to converge. A sequence converges, iff all of it's subsequences converge. Taking an arbitrary subsequence of $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ we get for every $\varepsilon>0$ some $N_1$ for the odd indices and some $N_2$ for the even such that $$|a_n-a|\leq \varepsilon$$ for all $n\geq \max\{N_1, N_2\}$.

But the rate of convergence completly gets lost, take $x_{2m}=a$ as the constant sequence of your limit. That surely converges superlinear, take any other superlinear convergent sequence with the same limit now we see that for  $$|x_{k+1}-a| \leq \mu \cdot |x_k -a|^r$$  there surely  aren't $\mu, r$ such that it holds for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Edit: Assuming the sequence to be strictly increasing makes things much easier as the convergence of $x_{2m}$ is already enough to conclude $x_m$  converges. In this case the rate of convergence gets lost too, I mention an idea for a counterexample in the comments.

Comment: Thank you. Since it is a strictly increasing sequence, I wonder whether to taking the constant sequence is possible.

Comment: @chp61 oh wait you have a strict increasing sequence? that makes it kind of pathological because then it is enough that $x_{2m}$ converges as $$x_{2m} < x_{2m+1} < x_{2m+2}$$ and with sandwich you see that $x_{2m+1}$ converges too. Much easier is just saying that $x_{2m}$ must be bounded and its bound bounds $x_m$ too hence $x_m$ converges. But nevertheless the rate of convergence can get much worse, the main idea is taking something that converges very fast like $-\frac{1}{2^n}$ as the even indices and add a tiny bit for the odd such that the quotient converges to 1

Comment: for sure i mean that one of the accumulation points of $\frac{|x_{n+1} -a|}{|x_n - a|}$ is one

Comment: Thank you! Regarding the rate of convergence for combined subsequences, if I divide the sequence $\{x_m\}$ into $\{x_i\}$ for $i\in I$ and $\{x_j\}$ for $j\in J$, where $N=I\cup J$, can the same argument be possible? Thank you in advance..