# The Limits of Measurable Functions

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, measurable-functions

The question I have received is the following:

Consider R equipped with a lebesgue measure. Let $f_1, f_2, ...$ be measurable functions on R with $f_1(x)\leq f_3(x)$ for all $x,f_2(x)\leq f_4(x)$ for all $x$, $f_3(x)\leq f_5(x)$ for all $x$, and so forth. Is it the case that $$lim_{j\to +\infty}\int f_j\:{d\mu(x)}=\int lim_{j\to +\infty}\: f_j\:{d\mu(x)}\:?$$

Either give a prove or a counterexample. What positive conclusion can you draw from these hypotheses?

---

So I attempted this question by providing the following counterexample:

I constructed the sequence of functions such that all the functions with even subscripts are the constant function 0, and all the odd functions are the constant function 1. Clearly, then the equality does not hold, so the first part of the question is complete, it is not the case. However, I am not sure what positive conclusion I can draw from these hypotheses, I am not quite sure what is expected? Am I looking at the question in the wrong way?

Comment: Is it assumed that $\lim_{j \to \infty} f_j$ exists? (pointwise or a.e.) If not, then the RHS of the proposed equality is not even defined, so certainly it's false, as your example demonstrates.

Comment: The question does not seems to state that, do you think it is implied? Because I suppose without it the counterexample is quite trivial. I suppose the followup question is can I construct a counterexample where the RHS limit exists?

Comment: If the limit on the RHS exists, then equality does hold. You can apply the monotone convergence theorem to the even and odd subsequences to conclude that they both converge, to the same limit (in the extended real numbers, i.e. the limit may be finite or infinite). This implies that [the sequence itself converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/589167/if-x-2m-and-x-2m-1-converge-to-the-same-limit-does-x-m-co).

Comment: I understand why both subsequences converge, but why are they converging to the same limit?

Comment: If you assume that $\lim_{j\to \infty} f_j$ exists (call it $f$), then all subsequences of $f_j$, including the even and odd subsequences $f_{2j}$ and $f_{2j+1}$, converge to $f$. So, applying the MCT to each of these two subsequences, we get $\lim_{j \to \infty} \int f_{2j} = \int f$ and $\lim_{j \to \infty} \int f_{2j+1} = \int f$.

Comment: @ Bungo MCT requires an additional hypothesis, like non-negativity. See my answer for a counterexample.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yeah, I glossed over that. Actually non-negativity is overkill; it suffices to assume that $\int f_j > -\infty$ for all $j$. Then make the argument outlined in my previous comment using $f_j - f_1$ for odd $j$, and $f_j - f_2$ for even $j$. But you're right, the hypothesis that $\int f_j > -\infty$ is not given in the problem statement. (Nor, as noted above, do we even have the hypothesis that $\lim f_j$ exists.)

Comment: @Bungo I agree with your comments. The original problem had no extra condition to make MCT work so I though I should give a counter-example.

Answer (score 1):

Non-negativity is missing in the hypothesis. Even if $\lim f_n$ exist equality may not hold. Example: $f_n =-I_{(n,\infty)}$ The entire  sequence is increasing and $\lim f_n (x)=0$ for all $x$. But $\lim \int f_n =-\infty$ whereas $\int  \lim f_n =0$.