# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{T_n+1}}{n},$ where $T_n$ is the $n$th Triangular number

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, harmonic-numbers

Consider the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+1}}{n}=1+\dfrac12-\dfrac13-\dfrac14+\dfrac15+\dfrac16-\cdots.$$ This is clearly not absolutely convergent. On the other hand, obvious choice, alternating series does not work here. Seems like the partial sum sequence is bounded but it is not monotone.

How can we prove that this series converges? and, where does it converge to?

Comment: A direction is considering triangular numbers mod 4, to obtain boundedness of partial sum of $(-1)^{T_n}$. Then apply Dirichlet's theorem.

Comment: @SungjinKim: Thank you very much. I completely forgot the Dirichlet's test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that
$$
\left| {\sum\limits_{n = 1}^N {( - 1)^{T_n  + 1} } } \right| \le 2
$$
for any $N\geq 1$. Also $\frac{1}{n}\to 0$ monotonically. Hence, by Dirichlet's test, the series converges. The limit is
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^{T_n  + 1} }}{n}} & = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{N \to  + \infty } \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{2N} {\frac{{( - 1)^{T_n  + 1} }}{n}}  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{N \to  + \infty } \left( {\sum\limits_{n = 1}^N {\frac{{( - 1)^{n + 1} }}{{2n - 1}}}  + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^N {\frac{{( - 1)^{n + 1} }}{{2n}}} } \right)
\\ &
 = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{N \to  + \infty } \sum\limits_{n = 1}^N {\frac{{( - 1)^{n + 1} }}{{2n - 1}}}  + \mathop {\lim }\limits_{N \to  + \infty } \sum\limits_{n = 1}^N {\frac{{( - 1)^{n + 1} }}{{2n}}}  = \frac{\pi }{4} + \frac{1}{2}\log 2.
\end{align*}

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: @Gary 1+ There is no need to prove convergence first. In partial sums you can rearrange terms as you like, just as you did. You have then found two partial sums which each have a finite limit. Hence the complete partial sum converges to the sum of those limits which in turn is by definition the value of the original infinite sum. This also shows a posteriori that the sum is convergent.

Answer (score 2):

The triangular numbers alternate odd, odd, even, even, odd, odd, even, even, etc. The reason is that to move from $T_n$ to $T_{n+2}$, we add $n + (n + 1) = 2n + 1$, an odd number, so we obtain an alternating pattern of parities for $T_n$, over the odd and even integers $n$.

So, consider grouping the terms in pairs:
$$\left(1+\frac12\right)-\left(\frac13+\frac14\right)+\left(\frac15+\frac16\right)-\ldots = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\left(\frac{1}{2n-1} + \frac{1}{2n}\right).$$
This series is convergent, using the alternating series test.

Because the terms of the original series converge to $0$, this also implies that the original series is convergent too.

Comment: In order to groups the terms, first you have to prove that the series converges. Otherwise series like $\sum(-1)^n$ would be convergent by the same reasoning. As Sungjin Kim wrote in his comment,  Dirichlet's test works here. What do you think about my second question?

Comment: The pattern can also be derived from $T_n-1=\frac12(n-1)(n+2)$, so $T_n$ is odd iff $4|(n-1)(n+2)$, i.e. $4|n-1\lor4|n-2$. Indeed, the exponent in the original problem, $T_n+1$, might as well be $T_n-1$.

Comment: @Bumblebee No, you can group the terms, study the grouped-term series, and use that to prove that the OP series converges. The author of this answer does that with the comment at the end: "Because the terms of the original series converge to $0$..." That is not the case with $\sum(-1)^n$. Any partial sum of the OP series is a partial sum of the grouped-term series, possibly added to a lone term from the original series. Since those lone terms converge to $0$, then partial sums of the OP series converge to the same number that partial sums of the grouped-term series converge to.

Comment: @alex.jordan: I see. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

The sequence of partial sums is $s_n=s_{n-1}+\frac{(-1)^{T_n+1}}{n}$, and if we can partition the sequence into two subsequences which converge to the same value, it implies the original sequence converges as well. This is usually done by looking at subsequences made by odd and even indeces, see for example [If $\{x_{2m}\}$ and $\{x_{2m-1}\}$ converge to the same limit, does $\{x_m\}$ converge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/589167). Notice that we don't need to care about terms re-arrangements since we will be working only with finite partial sums.

So we consider two subsequences by splitting the $s_n$ for and even $s_{2n}$ and odd $s_{2n-1}$ subsequences. Since trinagular numbers parity is periodic modulo $4$, we can write these explicitly in terms of $s_{4n},s_{4n-2}$ and $s_{4n-1},s_{4n-3}$. For example for the even indexes subsequence, say $b_{n}$ such that $b_{2n}=s_{4n}$ and $b_{2n-1}=s_{4n-2}$, applying the recurrence above we can see that 
$$
b_{2n}=b_{2n-1}-\frac{1}{4n-1}-\frac{1}{4n},
b_{2n-1}=b_{2n-2}+\frac{1}{4n-3}+\frac{1}{4n-2}\\
$$ 
which together with $b_1=s_2=\frac{3}{2}$ describes the sequence completely.   But this is indeed the sum 
$$b_n=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k+1} \left(\frac{1}{2k-1}+\frac{1}{2k}\right).$$
Similarly for the sequence $a_n$ of odd terms $a_{2n}=s_{4n-1}$, $a_{2n-1}=s_{4n-3}$, we arrive at

$$
a_{2n}=a_{2n-1}+\frac{1}{4n-2}-\frac{1}{4n-1},a_{2n-1}=a_{2n-2}+\frac{1}{4n-4}-\frac{1}{4n-3}
$$ 
with $a_1=s_1=1$, corresponding to
$$a_n=1+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(-1)^{k} \left(\frac{1}{2k-2}+\frac{1}{2k-1}\right).$$
Now both sequences clearly converge by the alternating series test, so we are left with showing they converge to the same value. But since both of the sums are themselves just added $\frac{\pi}{4}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}$ (Leibniz formula) and taylor series for natural logarithm $\ln(1+x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}x^k$ for $x=1$. So, as already shown in the other answer, indeed
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} s_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = \frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\ln 2}{2}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

The triangle numbers themselves follow the pattern of

$$odd, odd, even, even, odd, odd, even, even, \ldots$$

This can be shown as this pattern alternates whether or not the even number in $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ is $0,2 \mod 4$. So as you can see in your sum, the terms will alternate in a pattern of twos.

Now if we group these terms of the series as follows

$$
(1+1/2)-(1/3+1/4) +(1/5+1/6) - \ldots = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\dfrac{1}{2n-1}-\dfrac{1}{2n}\right)
$$

which converges via the alternating series test, and according to Wolfram alpha, it converges to the value of 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\dfrac{1}{2n-1}-\dfrac{1}{2n}\right) = \dfrac{1}{4}(\pi+2\log(2))
$$

**However** you can only associate the series if it converges, so that associative step we made assumes that your initial series converges. I'd expect your initial series to converge, however I am much to tired and need to sleep!

Comment: I also can plug this into Wolfram alpha myself. Doesn't seems like a complete/helpful answer. In fact the second summation is different from the first one, therefore wrong.

Comment: I was just trying to come up with a temporary answer that gave you the value of the infinite limit. It certainly isn't my finest work but it was 3am and I was right about to sleep, but Sil has a very robust answer that fills in all the holes from my work here

Answer (score 1):

$$1\color{red}{+\frac12}\color{blue}{-\frac13}-\frac14+\frac15\color{cyan}{+\frac16}\color{magenta}{-\frac17}+\cdots$$

$$=1\color{red}{-\frac12+2\cdot\frac12}\color{blue}{+\frac13-2\cdot\frac13}-\frac14+\frac15\color{cyan}{-\frac16+2\cdot\frac16}\color{magenta}{+\frac17-2\cdot\frac17}+\cdots$$

$$=1-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\frac15-\cdots+2\left(\frac12-\frac13+\frac16-\frac17+\cdots\right)$$

$$=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{4n-2}-\frac{1}{4n-1}$$

$$=\ln(2)+\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n-1/2}-\frac{1}{n-1/4}$$

$$=\ln(2)+\frac12\left(H_{-1/4}-H_{-1/2}\right)$$

$$=\ln(2)+\frac12\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\ln(2)\right)$$

$$=\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac12\ln(2)$$

note that we used the series representation of the harmonic number

$$H_a=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+a}\Longrightarrow H_a-H_b=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n+b}-\frac{1}{n+a}$$
and we also used the results $H_{-1/4}=\frac{\pi}{2}-3\ln(2)$ and $H_{-1/2}=-2\ln(2)$ which can be obtained from the integral representation of the harmonic number $H_a=\int_0^1\frac{1-x^a}{1-x}dx$.